# Why is crontab not executing my .sh file?

Tags: bash, crontab, ubuntu-20.04

I am completely and utterly confused at why crontab with not run this .sh file. I'm using a package called **pushover notifications** to send a notification to my phone. I've tried so many different methods and non of then seem to work. The file can be run in the terminal just fine. It works with a startup application executer, but it refuses to run by just pressing the "run" button. This is the code I am trying to run in crontab.

```
#!/bin/sh 
pushover-cli push "$HOSTNAME is going offline. Wait to access files until startup message."
```

In crontab I've tried just putting the raw code, adding a command to open the terminal and run the file in it, using `./filename`, `cd /home/filelocation && sh filename.sh`, and so many other things but nothing seems to work.

Comment: generally speaking. its time to add logging so you can see what happens when it launches and runs.

Comment: Looks like this command requires an internet connection. When your cron service is stopping, is the network still up? // Oh yeah, and is it running as the correct user? To which crontab did you add it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after a little more research i found a bash script that works. https://github.com/akusei/pushover-bash

Edit, still having trouble with crontab

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If this doesn't answer your initial question, you should delete it and instead [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1774519/edit) your original question so that it reflects your current situation. "Still having trouble" doesn't tell much, you should specify what trouble exactly you have.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
which pushover-cli
```

This will give you the full path to the executable. Insert the full path into your shell script, instead of just the command-name. So something like:

```
#!/bin/sh 
/usr/local/bin/pushover-cli push "$HOSTNAME is going offline. Et cetera"
```

or wherever your `pushover-cli` is.

Also, make sure that the full path name of your script is in your crontab.